# How should I comment python code?

Tags: python, comments

I often see comments in open source or "professional" python code -- like webapp2 or webob, that look very spaced out. The comments seem to outnumber the code. I have noticed individual developers do this in their own apps too. Big spacing, lots of comments, and then a few lines of code every so often.

I suppose I like this style, it does feel more organised. And now that I'm larger projects in python I wonder if maybe I should organize a big project with code and comments like what I have seen others do. I think it might make it more readable and maintainable, as well as maybe make me a better coder -- since things will be clearer.

**just thought : is this question better on code review? *to hear is to obey***

Currently I just comment like this, for example :

```
    #U - Idempotent. b-atching requests 
    # which can be PUT, DELETE or GET. 
    #@control.access.collector_or_owner        
    def patch(s,*a,**k):
            s.resolve(*a,**k)
            for mod in s.requested_modifications:
                    method = mod.get('method') or 'PUT'
                    point = s.current_point+mod.get('point') or ''
                    body = mod.get('body') or ''
                    s.say('Will execute %s on %s for %s\n' % (method,point,body))
                    # create the in-app request
                    mod_request = webapp2.Request.blank(point)
                    mod_request.body = str(body)
                    mod_request.method = method
                    mod_request.app = s.app
                    # then find the handler and report
                    execute_tuple = s.app.router.match(mod_request)
                    mod_request.route,mod_request.route_args,mod_request.route_kwargs = execute_tuple
                    handler = mod_request.route.handler
                    if handler not in s.app.router.handlers:
                            s.app.router.handlers[handler] = handler = webapp2.import_string(handler)
                    else:
                            handler = s.app.router.handlers[handler]
                    s.say('Will execute %s on %s for %s via %s\n' % (method,point,body,execute_tuple))
                    # then execute
                    in_app_response = webapp2.Response()
                    handler = handler(mod_request,in_app_response)
                    handler.dispatch() 
                    s.say('Response is %s\n' % (in_app_response))
```

Which just focusses on the "what is to be done" but doesn't explain anything else. I'm sure there is a better way, but instead of just coming up with my own better way I want the wisdom of the sages.

I've had a read of the [Style Guide PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments) -- and it is helpful, but something that distills the wisdom of comment *auteurs* for big complex python projects with a little more detail than "When writing English, Strunk and White apply" is required.

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I'm not a sage.

Python is very readable in and of itself, but I've usually seen a lack of spacing that detracts from its readability. I mainly use spacing/comments to show structure in the code, with the occasional use for explaining tricky blocks of code. For the latter case, it's generally better to restructure the code, making it less tricky if possible, instead of delving into long documentation.

Given Google's programming expertise, their [Python Style Guide (Comments)](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Comments) is usually a good resource.

Answer (score 2):

Documenting the function should be done in a [docstring](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings). Your comments above the function are uncomprehensible for me. A docstring could look like this:

```
def patch(s,*a,**k):
    """Patch a ...

    Arguments:
    s - A ... object
    Any additional arguments are handed to s.resolve().

    Returns:
    bla

    Raises:
    ValuesError when s is not ...
    """
    s.resolve(*a,**k)
    for mod in s.requested_modifications:
        ...
```

The inline comments in your code aren't very helpful because they only decribe *what* the code does, effectively duplicating it.

Instead use comments do describe *why* code does something if it is not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but I feel it is relevant to the question.

In his seminal book *Code Complete*, Steve McConnell advocates first writing coarse pseudocode explaining *what* you want to accomplish, using words from the problem domain (e.g. "customers" instead of "list of CustomerRecords"). Then refine the pseudocode until it "feels easier to just write the code than refine it more" (paraphrased from memory).

Now comment out the pseudocode and fill in the real code underneath each line of pseudocode, and leave the pseudocode where it is, as it is now serves very nicely as comments that explain the *intent* of the code.

Comment: Yes, I think this is like what I am aiming for as one of my strategies for tackling bigger projects.Thanks!